# Cloudfront Origin Domain Name - should you include www

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

My nginx server is setup so that all URLs `example.com/url` are forwarded to `www.example.com/url`

In the cloudfront origin domain when I create the distribution should I enter
`example.com` or `www.example.com`
?

Will this make a difference in any case?